# Laravel assumes the database table is the plural form of the model name

Tags: laravel, eloquent

By default, Laravel is assuming that the database table is the plural form of the model name. But what if my table name is "news" and i still want to use this feature? should i change it to "newses" or should i use "new" for the model name?

Comment: I recomend you to use "newses" you avoid future headake

Comment: I would suggest singular `news` because at some point you will create a schema with a singular name then you have a nasty inconsistency/anti-pattern.  Another thing, instead of giving you the answer (like other people) I would comment a [reference to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) so you can help yourself in future :)

Comment: Note that newer versions of Laravel will use a set of rules to define what the table name should be: https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/blob/1.3.x/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector.php

Answer (score 38):

You may specify a custom table by defining a table property on your model as below

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'my_flights';
}
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

Comment: Next time you go copy and paste examples from the documenation please reference to it, so then you're helping people help themselves.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names

Answer (score 16):

If you have a model ending with the letter 's', it will keep the table name the same. In your case, your model will name your table `news` by default.

If you want to use another name though, you can use:

```
protected $table = 'tablename';
```

inside of your model.

EDIT: I tested this in my application. I made a model named `News`. Then I made a new instance of `News` and retrieved the table name:

```
$news = new News();
dd($news->getTable());
```

It returns: `news`

Answer (score 12):

Inside your eloquent model you have to define `table name`. For example if my model is named `user` and table in database is named `user_of_application` then i do it this way

```
class user extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_of_application';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Laravel uses a "standard set" rule that defines:

- A Model is a single instance of a record
- A Collection is one or more records

Therefore it assumes that a table is a collection of records.

The nomenclature has a problem when it clashes with various features / gotchas of human languages. For example, what if I have a Model called Sheep? That does mean my Database Table should be called "Sheeps"?

It's up to the developer to avoid "Gollum/Smeagol" syntax. Indeed, you wouldn't want a table called "Newses" as much I'd like to end up with a table called "Sheeps".

Ultimately, I construct Migrations with:

```
sudo php artisan make:migration create_sheep_table --create=sheep
```

As for Models, you'll notice in the documentation that they have a different table name for "Flights" called "my_flights"

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#defining-models

Again, it's up to the developer / DB manager to make decisions on naming conventions that make sense in an application context.

Comment: Too bad.. Laravel's big inspiration (Ruby on Rails) is the other framework notoriously using plural form for table names. But they include functionality to handle irregular plural. Which kinda defies their motto of keeping things simple.. Isn't there a tool for Laravel that serves this purpose?

Comment: For data administrators, table is a relation. When we do a select from any entity (table), with or wihtout joins etc., the result (if any) will be a relation. A relation could be formed by one or more rows. For data administrators, there is an entity, not a table. So it's better that its name be on singular. ORMs are not perfect, but developers have been doing improvements to not interfere in a decisions concerned to the relational database only. A relational database need to be structured based on business rules, without thinking in how programming languages will access their data.