# Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "expenses" does not exist

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

Since i am a spanish speaker, i wrote the controllers and models of income and expense in spanish; while all the rest were on english.. 
I renamed and changed manually Routes, Controllers, Migrations and even Models.
And when i run php artisan migrate:reset this is my error.

> Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "expenses" does not exist (SQL: alter table "expenses" drop column "location_id")**

I use psgql and laravel 5.3

*This is my code:*

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Expense extends Model
    {

        protected $fillable = ['id', 'description', 'quantity'];


        public function locations()
        {

            return $this->hasMany('App\Location');

        }
        public function icons()
        {

            return $this->hasMany('App\Icon');
        }
        public function types()
        {

            return $this->hasMany('App\Type');
        }
        public function stores()
        {

            return $this->hasMany('App\Store');
        }

    }
```

**Migration:**

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateExpensesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('expenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->float('quantity');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->integer('location_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('icon_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('type_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('store_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('expenses');
    }
}
```

**Location Migration:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateLocationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->float('lat');
            $table->float('long');
            $table->integer('store_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('store_id')->references('id')->on('stores')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        Schema::table('expenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('expenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('location_id');
        });

        Schema::dropIfExists('locations');
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Location extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'address', 'lat', 'long'];


    public function expenses()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Expense');
    }

    public function stores()
    {

        return $this->hasOne('App\Store');
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: What is it you don't understand?

Comment: I get those error when i try to migrate to psgql.

Comment: The error message is very clear - you don't have a table named expenses.

Comment: I actually migrated both tables, but when i use migrate:status i have an : N on them while the other tables are on Y.

Answer (score 8):

When it says

```
relation "expenses" does not exist
```

It usually happens when your expenses table must have been dropped before `migration:reset` rolled back `CreateLocationsTable`.

Check the order of execution of your migrations.

As you were trying to reset, to fix it now, open your database, drop all tables manually and execute `migrate` again.

Answer (score 2):

```
Schema::table('expenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

change this to

```
Schema::alter('expenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error. I had to resolve it by adding the prefix of the database to my model. There is a way to change this in the database, and it is supposed to be changed. it's something, like $user, public. It's the schema profile. Mine is changed when I login, but for some reason the model is not binding to schema. So I had to specify it in the model. Instead of

```
    protected $table = 'table_name';
```

I had to do

```
    protected $table = 'schema_name.table_name';
```

Note: By schema_name or table_name, I'm not referring for you to put schema_ then the name. That is just so it's easier to read.
The model is located in the model folder under the App/Models folder depending on which version of Laravel you using and how your Models are organized. If your model name is not the same as the table name, then you will need to put the protected $table. But if the schema is not there, then you will need to add that.

I do have this set in my DB_DATABASE_SECOND= in .env file. But it somehow still doesn't pick up the prefix.

But yeah. Pretty much I couldn't find the answer anywhere, but I

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solution found in:

- [Laravel assumes the database table is the plural form of the model name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674309/laravel-assumes-the-database-table-is-the-plural-form-of-the-model-name)
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names

you need to declare the singularity name of your table.

add this line

```
protected $table = 'expense'
```

at the end of your model file

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Expense extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'description', 'quantity'];


    public function locations()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Location');

    }
    public function icons()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Icon');
    }
    public function types()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Type');
    }
    public function stores()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Store');
    } 
    protected $table = 'expense';
}
```