# Laravel Undefined table: 7 ERROR

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm starting with this project in laravel, and Im configuring the environment locally.

I just set the database credentials in my .env file, also I did it in my config file, actually laravel console said I don't have sql exceptions, BUT when I try to make login it send me this: "QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "users" does not exist"

I executed the migrate command, I executed the seed command and they run fine.

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891205/undefined-table-7-error-relation-expenses-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your user table exist on your database (Check the spellings too) and also Change