# Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42P01) SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "suggesteds" does not exist LINE 1

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I was trying to create a migration in laravel using the code here. But unfortunately it pops out an error like given here.

I use PostgreSQL 9.2.24

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSuggestedsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('suggesteds', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('channel_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('group')->nullable()->index(); // 'technology', 
    'lifestyle', etc.
        $table->string('language')->default('en')->index();
        $table->integer('z_index')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    }

  /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function down()
   {
    Schema::dropIfExists('suggesteds');
   }
   }
```

Before i use MySQL and don't have its error.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try to delete entire database if you can and do migration again

Comment: This answer may help  -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891205/undefined-table-7-error-relation-expenses-does-not-exist

Comment: It may be error of  port, recheck  your  port  of  postgres

Answer (score 1):

Please use:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `suggesteds` table manually (if exist) from database and then run migration script again.

You should also check this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4063)

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSuggestedsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('suggesteds', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('channel_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('group')->nullable()->index();
            $table->string('language')->default('en')->index();
            $table->integer('z_index')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('suggesteds');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer, however this seems to be a pretty big code block with no explanation! Please consider adding an explanation on what this code does.