# Convention on Migration and Model Avenc Laravel

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-2019

Laravel Is it possible to not respect the naming conditions of migrations and templates because table names take "s" and template names take nothing. it is possible to circumvent this convention and how can this be done?

Comment: do you mean model instead of template. if so you can run two artisan commands one to create model `php artisan make:model Post` and then another to create migration `php artisan make:migration create_post_table_2022-03-03` Hope you get the point.

Comment: I did it but it didn't work it had to add an 's' to the name of my table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel assumes the database table is the plural form of the model name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674309/laravel-assumes-the-database-table-is-the-plural-form-of-the-model-name)

Comment: yes it does ! thanks